# My Score Count in Unity Keeps Randomly Going Down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Have a game where whenever you kill a zombie, you get one point. It works, however for some reason sometimes when I kill a zombie the score goes down a random amount even though I never coded it so that the score could go down. Here is the collision script which is where the score is counted. I am willing to answer any questions you guys have. Thank you!
Click here for the [Game Footage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5oUG.gif)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int killCount;
    public Text scoreCount;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("zombie"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            killCount += 1;
            scoreCount.text = "Kill Count: " + killCount.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to see if there was any specific pattern to the score going down but it seemed to bee completely random.

Comment: You must be using a different instance of the class or you are calling the constructor with 'new'.  The code posted only allows the killcount to increase.

Comment: Sadly there is not enough here to reproduce the issue

Comment: I edited in some gameplay so go see if that helps at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already pointed out the problem. You are running two instances of the `CollisionScript` on each sword. Depending on what sword collides with the zombie during the physics tick a different internal kill count is displayed. That's why the score sometimes jumps back a few values and then suddenly jumps back to a high value.

You can turn the `killCount` into static or make a `KillManager` that tracks the `killCount` instead.

```csharp
public class KillManager : MonoBehaviour
{
  private int killCount;
  public Text scoreCount;

  public void AddPoint()
  {
    killCount++;
    scoreCount.text = "Kill Count: " + killCount.ToString();
  }
}

public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  public KillManager manager;

  private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("zombie"))
    {
      Destroy(other.gameObject);
      manager.AddPoint();
    }
  }
}
```

This way you would never see the score decreasing, but you will notice another bug. If on the same physics tick both swords touch the same zombie you will receive two points. To resolve this you have a number of options.

### 1. Use a single box collider

In your case the swords are held in a box shaped manner. There is no good reason to fit two separate colliders snugly for each sword. A single box approximation would do and the player will none the wiser. One box means one collision and a single kill counter. The display isn't shared with another resource.

### 2. Add a killed bool to your Zombie

You could add a public bool to the script that your Zombie is running. When the sword meets the flesh of the undead you can quickly check the bool to see if the Zombie was already killed by something else. If it wasn't you increase the score and mark the zombie as killed.

```csharp
public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
{
  public bool killed = false;
}

public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  public KillManager manager;

  private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
  {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("zombie"))
    {
      Zombie zombie = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Zombie>();
      if(!zombie.killed)
      {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        manager.AddPoint();
        zombie.killed = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This all makes a lot of sense. I think i will go with the single box collider approach. Your a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

The present code does not decrease the counter. As @jdweng has commented, you are probably seeing the output of different instances of this calls.

I suggest making a few temporary changes for debugging. The idea is to give each instance of `CollisionScript` a unique number.

```cs
public class CollisionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static _globalCounter;       // <===
    private _number;                     // <===

    private int killCount;
    public Text scoreCount;

    public CollisionScript()             // <===
    {
        _number= ++_globalCounter;      // <===
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("zombie"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            killCount += 1;
            scoreCount.text = $"#{_number}: Kill Count: {killCount}";   // <===
        }
    }
}
```

Note that Unity does call the construct more often than you would expect, so don't worry about missing numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However this did not seem to work. I uploaded some gameplay so if you want you can see if that helps.